# Remote Desktop Connection - Dialog Box

Tags: remote-access, remote-server, remote-desktop

I need help
I know it sounds weird, so when I click the 'X' button to exit the Remote Connection, I accidentally checked the checkbox so that it won't show the dialog box again
My question is . Is there anyway I could retrieve back the dialog box from the Remote Desktop Connection

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The registry key to control this behavior is:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\ShowShutdownDialog (DWORD)
```

The values are:

- 0 = Show (default)
- 1 = Hide

So you should create that registry key (if it does not exist) and set the value to 0.